# Java function multiplying itself while printing?

Tags: java

I'm new to Java and I have a problem. I created a class that calculates factorial of n:

```
public class factorial {
double result=1;
public double equation (int x){
    for (int i=1;i<x+1;i=i+1) {
        result = result*i;
       }
       return result;
   }
}
```

I know I'm missing the case when x=0 but that's not the point Whenever I print it in other class it seems to multiply by itself

```
public class task1 {
factorial fa =new factorial();
void printit(){

        System.out.println(fa.equation(3));
        System.out.println(fa.equation(3));
        System.out.println(fa.equation(3));
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

task1 ta = new task1();

ta.printit();
}
}
```

Output:

```
6.0

36.0

216.0
```

How should I do it so it prints 6 three times instead of multiplying by itself

Comment: Declare `double result=1;` inside `equation` method

Comment: You want [Local Scope](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/) on your `result` variable.

Comment: Learn to use your IDE's debugger and you can discover the reason for yourself. Then your question would probably be: "Why is `result` not equal to one the second time I call method `equation()`?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to declare `result` inside the method `equation`. This way, the variable `result` is fresh whenever you run the method `equation`.

```java
public class factorial {
  public double equation (int x){
    double result = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < x + 1; i = i + 1) {
      result = result * i;
    }
    
    return result;
   }
}
```

If you *don't* do this, then the variable `result` stays the same with that instance of `factorial`. Also note that Java class names usually start with a capital letter, so instead of `factorial`, it would be `Factorial`.

Instead of `i = i + 1`, you can use `i++` or `i += 1`. Similarly, instead of `result = result * i`, you can do `result *= i`.

Some examples:

```
i = i + 10  ==  i += 10
i = i - 10  ==  i -= 10
i = i * 10  ==  i *= 10
i = i / 10  ==  i /= 10
i = i % 10  ==  i %= 10

i = i + 1  ==  i += 1  ==  i++
i = i - 1  ==  i -= 1  ==  i--
```